# Replace string in place by another string when line matching exactly another string with sed

Tags: bash, variables, sed, replace, in-place

In the following example (example.txt)

```
name1   stringA1    stringB1    stringC1
name2   stringA2    stringB2    stringC2
```

I'd like to replace in file 'stringB1' by 'new_string' lines that are matching 'name1' using variable.

I succeed to print lines of interest using:

```
NAME="name1"
sed -n "/^\<${NAME}\>/p" example.txt
```

But I'm having problem to print lines when I'm trying to make the substitution using bash variables:

```
NAME="name1"
STRING_TO_REPLACE="stringB1"
NEW_STRING="new_string"
sed -n "/^\<${NAME}\>/s/\<${STRING_TO_REPLACE}>/\<${NEW_STRING}\>/" example.txt
```

The final idea is to replace the string in file directly using sed -i option

```
sed -i "/^\<${NAME}\>/s/\<${STRING_TO_REPLACE}>/\<${NEW_STRING}\>/" example.txt
```

Comment: `sed "/$NAME/ s/$STRING_TO_REPLACE/$NEW_STRING/" file`?

Comment: you're using the wrong variable name ($PARENT) --> `sed "/^$NAME\>/s/\<$STRING_TO_REPLACE\>/$NEW_STRING/"`

Comment: @glennjackman good catch, my mistake! I edited my message

Comment: @Cyrus thanks it's working! My solution seems to be working too if I'm not using the -n option. I was using it to see only the modifications made but it seems it was a mistake.